# Exponential distribution with random variable as parameter

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let X be a random variable that distibuted exp(L) when L is random variable that distibuted exp($\lambda$)

I need to find $f_x(x)$

My first thought was maybe to use the rule of multiplication but it makes it even harder, next I thought about total probability but I can't figure out how to calculate this. Any hint?

Comment: Informally, $f(x) = \int f(x\vert L)f(L)\, dL$.

Comment: Where can I find proof for that?

Comment: Any book introducing conditional probability.

Comment: You want to use $$P[X\leq x] = \int_{0}^{\infty} P[X\leq x|L=t]\lambda e^{-\lambda t} dt$$

Answer (score 1):

$P(X \le x)=EP(X \le x|L)=E(1-e^{-Lx})=1-\int_0^{\infty} \lambda e^{-xy } e^{-\lambda y}dy=1-\frac {\lambda} {\lambda +x}$. Differentiaton  gives $f_X(x)=\frac {\lambda} {(\lambda +x)^{2}}, 0<x<\infty$.

Comment: L isn't constant, i think you calculated $f_{X/L}(x/L=l)$

Comment: I didn't treat $L$ as   a constant. I have used its distribution.

Comment: @geetha290krm: It’s possible OP uses ‘distributed $\exp(L)$’ to mean ‘exponentially distributed with parameter (mean?) $L$).’

Comment: I do not think the problem is $X=e^L$. I think the problem is $P[X> x|L=t] = e^{-xt}$ for all $t>0$, $x>0$. The conditional distribution of $X$, given $L=t$, is exponential with parameter $t$.